# Display photos geotag on MapBox iOS (Swift)

Tags: swift, mapbox

I would like to get something similar like in the picture.
I do not know how to load images as icons from a url.
The url image data is contained in json. I would also like to change the background under the number of the total number of tags. 
Could someone help me and show me an example of use?
Link to the photo below.

```
import Mapbox

   class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

   var mapView: MGLMapView!
   var icon: UIImage!
   var popup: UILabel?

   enum CustomError: Error {
      case castingError(String)
    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: MGLStyle.lightStyleURL)
       mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
       mapView.tintColor = .darkGray
       mapView.delegate = self
       view.addSubview(mapView)

       let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleMapTap(sender:)))
       for recognizer in mapView.gestureRecognizers! where recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
          singleTap.require(toFail: recognizer)
       }
       mapView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

       icon = UIImage(named: "port")
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
       let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!)

       let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",url: url,options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
       style.addSource(source)

       style.setImage(icon.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), forName: "icon")


       let ports = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "ports", source: source)
       ports.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "icon")
       ports.iconColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.9))
       ports.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster != YES")
       style.addLayer(ports)


       let stops = [
          20: UIColor.lightGray,
          50: UIColor.orange,
          100: UIColor.red,
          200: UIColor.purple
       ]


       let circlesLayer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPorts", source: source)
       circlesLayer.circleRadius = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))
        circlesLayer.circleOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0.75)
        circlesLayer.circleStrokeColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.75))
       circlesLayer.circleStrokeWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 2)
       circlesLayer.circleColor = NSExpression(format: "mgl_step:from:stops:(point_count, %@, %@)", UIColor.lightGray, stops)
       circlesLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster == YES")
       style.addLayer(circlesLayer)


       let numbersLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPortsNumbers", source: source)
       numbersLayer.textColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white)
       numbersLayer.textFontSize = NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))
       numbersLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
       numbersLayer.text = NSExpression(format: "CAST(point_count, 'NSString')")

       numbersLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster == YES")
       style.addLayer(numbersLayer)
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I corrected. Thanks

Comment: @Ryan Could you give me a simple example? Please

Answer (score 0):

In most map SDKs, you can use annotation for this.

`MGLMapView` also has those methods to add or remove annotations.

> /**
>    Adds an annotation to the map view.
>
> @note `MGLMultiPolyline`, `MGLMultiPolygon`, `MGLShapeCollection`, and
>       `MGLPointCollection` objects cannot be added to the map view at this time.
>       Any multipoint, multipolyline, multipolygon, shape or point collection
>       object that is specified is silently ignored.
>
> @param annotation The annotation object to add to the receiver. This object
>       must conform to the `MGLAnnotation` protocol. The map view retains the
>       annotation object. */
>   - (void)addAnnotation:(id )annotation;
>
> /**
>    Adds an array of annotations to the map view.
>
> @note `MGLMultiPolyline`, `MGLMultiPolygon`, and `MGLShapeCollection` objects
>       cannot be added to the map view at this time. Nor can `MGLMultiPoint`
>       objects that are not instances of `MGLPolyline` or `MGLPolygon`. Any
>       multipoint, multipolyline, multipolygon, or shape collection objects that
>       are specified are silently ignored.
>
> @param annotations An array of annotation objects. Each object in the array
>       must conform to the `MGLAnnotation` protocol. The map view retains each
>       individual annotation object.
>    */
>   - (void)addAnnotations:(NS_ARRAY_OF(id ) *)annotations;
>
> /**
>    Removes an annotation from the map view, deselecting it if it is selected.
>
> Removing an annotation object dissociates it from the map view entirely,
>    preventing it from being displayed on the map. Thus you would typically call
>    this method only when you want to hide or delete a given annotation.
>
> @param annotation The annotation object to remove. This object must conform
>       to the `MGLAnnotation` protocol
>    */
>   - (void)removeAnnotation:(id )annotation;
>
> /**
>    Removes an array of annotations from the map view, deselecting any selected
>    annotations in the array.
>
> Removing annotation objects dissociates them from the map view entirely,
>    preventing them from being displayed on the map. Thus you would typically
>    call this method only when you want to hide or delete the given annotations.
>
> @param annotations The array of annotation objects to remove. Objects in the
>       array must conform to the `MGLAnnotation` protocol.
>    */
>   - (void)removeAnnotations:(NS_ARRAY_OF(id ) *)annotations;

So, the first step will be add annotations to the map view with above methods. Then the `MGLMapView` will invoke one of its delegate method below:

`func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView?`

What you need is just return an appropriate view.
method.